# Call function and modify called variable in one operation

Tags: python

Essentially, I was wondering if you could  merge these 2 lines:

```
items = ["cat","apple","taco"]

def change(x):
  return(items[x-1])

temp = change(2)  # THIS ONE AND
temp = "orange"   # THIS ONE
```

It's difficult for me to explain, my apologies. I essentially just want to be able to get rid of that temp variable or a least only have to use it once.

Comment: The second line overwrites the result of the first, so you can just remove the first line.

Comment: are you trying to modify a value in `items`?

Comment: @Jacob What is your script supposed to do? In its current form, it looks like you're trying (but failing) to replace "apple" (the second element of the list items) with "orange"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just something like:

```py
items = ["cat","apple","taco"]

def change(ind, tx):
  items[ind-1] = tx

change(2, "orange")
print(items)
# >>> ['cat', 'orange', 'taco']
```